# Studying progression on proving Wilf's conjecture

Tags: combinations, analytic-number-theory

Currently I'm studying the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608085v1.pdf and here its written $|\{n \leq x \mid f(n) \neq 0\}|=O(x^{\frac{2}{3}})$ (where $f(n)$ is defined in the paper) can anyone please give reference to the paper where the above mentioned result is given ?

Comment: It is mentioned in the article, reference $[45]$.

Comment: Yes I saw that but I couldn't find after googling ? can you please give a link ?

Comment: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v8i1r19